# I need to write a comment, but I have only 48 reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I need to write a comment to a solution.

As far as I know I need 50 reputation points for this, **but**, I only have 48!
This really sucks.

What can I do?

Thanks for the answers, I now have 53 reputation ;-)

But here 1 more thing:
Can't the current system be exploited when 2 or more accounts are created by one person?

Comment: Move on and find something else to answer that isn't as vague

Comment: I still think it's a problem of the system. either use some form of fuzzy logic to say who can post a comment or give an option for a user to earn quickly 2 to 5 points. this is simply too much headache. and it costs about 3 hours of my time. people don't like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

accept an answer. They give you 2 rep points.

Answer (score 2):

Enter a user name on your profile.  So that it is pretty obvious that you want to part of this thing instead of being a numbered user.  Nobody *really* cares about nameless faceless people.

Comment: Interestingly software is written for nameless, faceless users. This might explain the cause of some quality issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a good answer to another question, or ask a good question on the site. You only need one upvote to gain the privilege to comment on other posts, which is pretty easy to get.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically answered your own question. You're right, you cannot leave comments until you have reached 50 reputation (except on your own posts). The number 50 was not picked arbitrarily; the admins wanted people to have been around for long enough to earn 50 rep before leaving comments. So, the only thing you can do is earn two more rep.